# ipfsアドレスまたはURLを隠蔽するには？

Tags: url, p2p, proxy, ipfs

ipfsはノードに分散してデータが保存されるため、ピンどめを解除したとしてもデータが消去される保証がありません。実用上はCRUDが実現できないと用途がかなり限定されてしまうので、ipfsアドレスの隠蔽をしたいと考えています。
ipnsアドレスをリンクさせたとしても、ipnsアドレスからipfsアドレスの逆引きが可能なため、隠蔽を行う事ができないようです。

ipfsアドレスの隠蔽（またはURLの隠蔽）をする場合、どんな方法が最善でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

アドレスをどうやって隠すかではなく、アドレスは知られた上でリソースへのアクセスをどう避けるかを考えることになるかなと思います。また、ネットワーク越しに第三者がアクセスできる以上、IPFS に限らずともリソースの完璧な削除は難しいと考えるべきでしょう。

まず IPFS に限った話をすると、公式ドキュメントにプライバシーについての言及があります: https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/privacy-and-encryption/

公開ネットワークに接続してファイルをやり取りしたい場合、CID は知られてしまいますし第三者が pin する可能性があります。したがって自前で暗号化などの手段を講じるかプライベートネットワークを作ってしまうかという方向性になります。しかも暗号はいつまでも暴かれないとは限りません。

URL 一般の話をすると、そもそもリソースの在りかを共有するためのものが URL であり、URL を隠すことは URL の役割ではありません。URL 文字列の中にパスワードのような文字列を含ませることによって総当たり攻撃にかかる時間を延ばすとか、URL の参照先で認証認可を実装するとかいったやり方は知られています。

補足：IPFS からのファイル削除については https://github.com/ipfs-inactive/faq/issues/9（あるいは https://discuss.ipfs.tech/t/can-i-delete-my-content-from-the-network/301）でも議論されています。